# Firefox cannot post form

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I'm unable to post my form in firefox. What firefox does is it reloads the same page and displays the username and password in the url as a query string despite using method 'post' in my form. I'm using a bootstrap modal dialog for filling the form. Kindly assist.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Assume you are using ajax request for your form, to stop form reloads the page you need to stop form default actions, to do so you can use PreventDefault(). here is a example for better understanding how it works

```
$(function () {
    var frm = $('#yourform');
    frm.submit(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/send.php',
            data: frm.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert('ok');
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: @joeabala glad it helped ! you may mark my answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, when using ajax to post a form you need to prevent default action of ajax. use e.preventDefault() as described by @moein above.